# Core Plot sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex with 2 pie chart

Tags: ios, core-plot, pie-chart, donut-chart

I create a graph with 2 piechart plot like donutchart: First is "**pieChart**", second is "**centerDonut**".

centerDonut has only 1 slice, with white color, value 1.

if user press a slice of "pieChart" it works well with the right index.
If user press a slice of "centerDonut", methods return the istance of "pieChart" instead of "centerDonut".

Why happens that?
I try with `[self.centerDonut zPosition:1]`, but it doesn't work.

```
-(void)initPlot {
[self configureHost];
[self configureGraph];
 //in configureChart I configure and add the pieChart and then the centerDonuts
[self configureChart];
 //I have 2 label in storyboard over the graph, set value of them and display.
[self totLabelsOverAll];
}
```

Comment: Are the pie charts in the same graph? Assuming they are concentric like in the *Plot Gallery* example app, have you set the `pieInnerRadius` on the `pieChart` to make it a ring instead of a full circle?

Comment: Hello Eric, thank for reply. Yes Are in the same graph, and no, I haven't set pieInnerRadius: I try it now and than I will let you know if it work. Thank you :)

Comment: Edit: @EricSkroch, In pieChart I set `self.pieChart.pieRadius = (self.hostView.bounds.size.height * 0.85) / 2;`, in centerDonut I set `self.centerDonut.pieInnerRadius = (self.hostView.bounds.size.height * 0.475) / 2;`. Do I have to set same innerradius in the pieChart? Thanks

Comment: @EricSkroch: it works like a charm! :D I edit  `self.centerDonut.pieInnerRadius` to `self.centerDonut.pieRadius`, and I add `self.pieChart.pieInnerRadius` with same value of `self.centerDonut.pieRadius`. Thank you very much! if you answer the question I will mark yours as right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `pieInnerRadius` on the `pieChart` to make it a ring.